# hard coded values in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, hardcode

What are hard **coded values** and how do we use it in **Dart**? I need some examples with code and explanation.
Thank you, God bless you
new to **flutter** and **dart**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hardcoded value is one that is not variable, meaning that it will always evaluate to the same thing.

Let's say that your app is a calculator, and you want it to perform a sum, if you made the user only input the numbers to be summed like first_number and second_number, but the operator was a constant defined in your code like "+", then you can say that the operation is hardcoded, regardless of language.

If instead you could choose from different types of operators ("+", "-", "*", "/") and then you performed a switch case where you evaluate the operator and perform a different operation on first_number and second_number accordingly, then that's dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

A hard-coded value by definition is a value that does not change based on user input. Variables are values that can change.

Example:

```
int x = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());   // get input from user
int y = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());   // get input from user

// user inputs x=4, y=10
print(x+y);   // answer is 14 based on user input
print(5+2)    // answer is 7 because values never change
```